# How to prevent background-image for text area from scrolling in IE7?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

I am just a beginner in html. I am trying to use background image for text area. It looks fine in firefox but not in internet explorer.

```css
.txt_area{ 
    background-image:url(../images/textarea_normal.png); 
    background-color:transparent; 
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    color:#999999; 
    width:311px; 
    height:91px; 
    padding-left:35px; 
    padding-right:10px; 
    border:0px; 
    padding-top:10px; 
    padding-bottom:10px; 
    font-size:12px; 
}
.txt_area:focus{ 
    background-image:url(../images/textarea_focus.png); 
    color:#000000;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="message" class="txt_area" 
    onFocus="remove_email('message','Message');" 
    onKeyPress="chgclr('message','Message')"  
    rows="" name="message" cols="">Message</textarea>
```

In internet explorer if i enter text in the text area the background image also scrolls with the content. I am using ie7. How can i rectify it?

Comment: This article is missing something about scrolling in the title... Background image for textarea itself is a different issue...

Answer (score 3):

Try adding the background attachment property:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-attachment.asp

Comment: setting CSS to **background-attachment: scroll;** worked for me :)